# Gmail token expires frequently

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api

We have one account from which we are reading emails into our web app, for this, we use google token authentication process as suggested in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php?pli=1. After
executing "$php quickstart.php" one code is generated, that code is manually entered to authenticate the account.

Earlier, it was working fine. But from the past 4-5 weeks, it has been observed that token is getting expired frequently (every 1 hr).
May I know, why is this happening? Google has added any kind of security constraint? What we can do to avoid frequent expiration of token.

Comment: Have you changed your scopes lately? If not try to remove the token and auto generate a new one (jus run your code) and let me know if the issue keeps persisting.